# vim command to map keys to command that maps keys

Tags: vim

Background:  I'm using this mapping `map ,r :! bundle exec ruby %<CR>` all the time to easily run test file I'm currently editing. However I also do:

```
map ,t :! bundle exec ruby test/integration/some_integration_test.rb<CR>
```

so that I can run this particular integration test with two key strokes *while working on some other file*. It has hard-coded path, when I move to some other area of the application I type above command with another integration test file path.

How to make a command that creates such mapping automatically?

`map ,T :map ,t :! bundle exec ruby %<CR>` won't work because it doesn't expand % while creating the mapping, so ,t will always run current file (while I want it to run file I was editing at the time of creating the mapping).

[EDIT]: 
Slightly adjusted solution from the answer:

```
nnoremap ,r :! bundle exec ruby %<CR>
nnoremap ,T :let g:testfile = expand('%:p')
nnoremap ,t :! bundle exec ruby <C-r><C-r>=g:testfile<CR><CR>
```

- `,r` always runs file under cursor
- `,T` saves current file path under in a variable for running later
- `,t` runs file path stored previously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just save the current file name (best with a full absolute path to be immune against changes to the current directory; the `:p` modifier does that) in a variable, and insert the variable instead of `%` via `<C-r>`:

```
:noremap ,r :let g:testfile = expand('%:p')<Bar>! bundle exec ruby %<CR>
:noremap ,t :! bundle exec ruby <C-r><C-r>=g:testfile<CR><CR>
```

<sup>PS: I used `:noremap`, because that is generally safer and should be the first choice unless you really need remapping to occur.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
execute ":nnoremap ,t :! bundle exec ruby ".shellescape(expand('%:p'))."<CR>"
```

creates a `,t` mapping that will execute your test on what is the current file at the time of execution.

But each time you do that you'll lose the previous `,t`. I'm not sure that's what you want to do.

Comment: "But each time you do that you'll lose the previous ,t. I'm not sure that's what you want to do." - yes that's exactly what I want